# ef core throws exception when i try to save local entities

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Hellow. I have repository without call SaveChanges in methods:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public EfUnitOfWorkRepository(ContractBackendContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        await _context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

and I have UnitOfWork class:

```
   public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
   {
      private readonly ContractBackendContext _context;
      public UnitOfWork(ContractBackendContext context)
      {
         _context = context;
      }
      public IRepository<Student> StudentRepository{ get { return new Repository<Student>(_context);}}
      public IRepository<Group> GroupRepository{ get { return new Repository<Group>(_context); } }
      public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
      {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
    }
```

Group and Student have Many-To-Many relation.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string Id { get; set; }        
}
public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    ...fields
    public List<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}
public class Group: BaseEntity
{
    ...fields
    public List<Student> Students {get;set;}
}
```

ef core automatically created a table for them.

When i fill information in cycle and after call savechanges:

```
var groupRepository = _unitOfWork.GroupRepository;
foreach(var student in students){
   groupRepository.Students.Add(student);
}
await groupRepository.UpdateAsync(group);
await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

i get exception

```
MessageText: INSERT or UPDATE in the table "GroupStudent" violates the foreign key constraint "FK_GroupStudent_Groups_GroupsId"
Detail: The key (GroupsId)=(42cfb001-181b-4b0d-89a0-a7aa45e82da7) is missing in the table "Groups".
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: So, why not just use the DbContext directly as both your UnitOfWork and Repository implementation?  You're obviously struggling with the added complexity you've introduced.

Comment: I'm trying to use them in a separate project from the business logic. The cicle in one project and the implementation of UnitOfWork and Repository in another.

Comment: But neither one of those is business logic.  They are both data access plumbing, just like the DbContext.

Comment: The error is pretty clear that it cannot find a Group with the ID "42cfb001-181b-4b0d-89a0-a7aa45e82da7" which is being referenced by the student.  The fact that your relationship is many-to-many but your insert and update scenario is dealing with a singular group looks fairly out of place.

Comment: No, group with this Id is created local and when ef try to save records in database throws exception